# jes-sherborne / jquery-signature-panel-plugin: post URL to asp variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, signature

I have been implementing jes-sherborne/jquery-signature-panel-plugin. I am at the point where I have signatures successfully posting to the signatures folder.

I need to record the url path of the last signature in a variable in the current record.

I have achieved this with a webcam app in the same project but am having difficulties with the signature image (.png).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function signatureOK(signatureData) {
        // Send the signature to the server and generate an image file.
        $.ajax({
            url:"process_signature.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:JSON.stringify(signatureData),
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"text",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                $("#latest-signature").attr("src", data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
        $("#my-panel").signaturePanel("clear");
    }

    function signatureCancel() {
        alert("You clicked Cancel.");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#my-panel").signaturePanel({
            okCallback: signatureOK,
            cancelCallback: signatureCancel
        });
    });

</script>
```

The field I am trying to save the signature in is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="x_image" id="x_image" value="<%= Server.HTMLEncode(Table1.image.CurrentValue&"") %>">
```

The code I used to successfully save a webcam captured image to a variable was:

```
function my_completion_handler(msg) {
        // extract URL out of PHP output
        if (msg.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
            var image_url = RegExp.$1;
            // show JPEG image in page
            $("#x_image").val(image_url); //update <Field Name>

$("#x_image"). // being the field name.
```

I have tried implementing the same structure but have failed. Have been chopping and changing for days. I am very new to this and any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by changing code:

```
function signatureOK(signatureData) {
        // Send the signature to the server and generate an image file.
        $.ajax({
            url:"process_signature.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:JSON.stringify(signatureData),
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"text",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                $("#latest-signature").attr("src", data);
```

To:

```
function signatureOK(signatureData) {
        // Send the signature to the server and generate an image file.
        $.ajax({
            url:"process_signature.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:JSON.stringify(signatureData),
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"text",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                $("#latest-signature").attr("src", data);
            var img_src = $('#latest-signature').attr('src');
                          $("#x_image").val(img_src);
```

This is now posting the URL of the image to the image variable. This now displays the signature on my list page.